# Is there a technique for analyzing the relationship between time-series clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, clustering, algorithm-request

I have two time-series datasets (temperature and speed of the vehicle). I will use Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering and DTW to cluster both datasets.

I am looking for a technique (like regression model) to find the relationship between two time-series clustered data. I am curious to find the relationship between changes in temperature and vehicle speed. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have no clue. Good question.